# SQL - Change a value inside a move table query

Tags: mysql

I want to move multiple record from table.A to table.B. And I wanna to change value for one of field of table.B.

```
INSERT INTO Temp (F1,F2,F3)
SELECT A1, A2, A3 from Record where ID = @id
```

For example above, I need to set F3 always is "Hello" in table "Temp" regardless how many records moving. It is possible to do it?

I need to do moving and changing in same time because many people can move out record in one time. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting the `Hello` string in place of `A3`:

```
INSERT INTO Temp (F1,F2,F3)
SELECT A1, A2, 'Hello' from Record where ID = @id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Temp (F1,F2,F3)
SELECT A1, A2, 'Hello' from Record where ID = @id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the value of A3 with `Hello` since A3 is not needed in your case

```
INSERT INTO 
     Temp (F1,F2,F3)
SELECT 
     A1, A2, 'HELLO'
From 
    Record 
Where ID = @id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
you can try this:
 INSERT INTO Temp (F1,F2,F3)
 SELECT A1, A2, 'Hello' from Record where ID = @id
```

Comment: yes.i not see any of the other answers while I answered